Building TOC in sphinx that reflects project folder structure
I want to autogenerate documentation for a python project. I managed to get a barebones pipeline working with sphinx, but the output is not very pretty and I would appreciate some guidance on how to make the output cleaner and the inputs more maintainable.
My project is organized like so:
docs
   |-- build
   |-- index.rst
   |-- conf.py
app
   |-- main_app.py #entry point that intializes everything, internal imports in .py files are relative to here
   views
      |-- view1.py
      |-- view2.py
      |-- ...
   controllers
      |-- controller1.py
      |-- ...
   models
      |-- model1.py
      |-- ...
   utils
      |-- ...
   plugins
      |-- ...

The table of contents that is generated is flat, like the below:
app
   app.controller.controller1
   app.models.model1
   app.utils.util1
   ...

I would prefer to have a table of contents with several nested levels that reproduces the folder structure of the app folder. How can I modify or redistribute my index.rst (below) to achieve this?
.. automodule:: app.utils.MetaReader
    :members:
...
.. automodule:: app.models.main_model
    :members:
...more automodule statements ...

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   :caption: Contents:



Build a nested structure of .rst files that reflects what you want.

And these would go where? Inside the same folders as the modules to be documented? How are they referenced from the main index.rst?

I'd put them in docs/api/GROUP_NAME/*.rst such that it mirrors your API file directory structure. In the docs/index.rst you would add a toctree entry for each api/GROUP_NAME/module.rst. You can also have index files within each nested folder. You can follow this 2-level deep example: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/main/docs/api

I'd put them in docs/api/GROUP_NAME/*.rst, such that it mirrors your API file directory structure.
In the docs/index.rst you would add a toctree entry for each api/GROUP_NAME/module.rst.
You can also have index files within each nested folder. You can follow this 2-level deep example: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/main/docs/api.
